# Check if number of digits of an integer is even with recursion

Tags: java, recursion

Need to check  if number of digits of an integer is even with recursion.

Here is without recursion:

```
private static boolean jeParanBrCifara(int n) {
    int brojCifara = String.valueOf(n).length();
    if (brojCifara % 2 == 0) 
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

and here is code for counting numbers with the recursion

```
public  int DigitsCount(int Number) {    
    if (Number > 0) {
        Count = Count + 1;
        DigitsCount(Number / 10);
    }
    return Count;
}
```

But how to make an recursive method that will take an integer as parameter and return true (if number of digits is even) of false ?

I did this, but not sure if it is correct:

```
static int Count = 0;
public static boolean isEven(int Number) {
    boolean even = false;
    if (Number > 0) {
        Count = Count + 1;
        isEven(Number / 10);
    }
    if (Count % 2 == 0) {
        even = true;
    }
    return even;
}
```

Any tips/hints?

Comment: The `count` variable in your `isEven` method is not used. It simply counts up to the number.

Comment: and what's wrong with saying `digitCount(number)%2`  in isEven?

Comment: Is the use of recursion required? I can see using recursion if this is a part of a problem set, or is necessary because of language limitations. As a practical issue, recursion is not appropriate for this problem. A loop based solution has rather much less overhead and is much easier to understand.

Comment: In the recursive method, be sure to set the base case.  If Number == 1 then false.  then you want to find out if the last number was even or odd.

Comment: Note in your first code block, that `if(bool) return true; else return false;` is the same as `return bool;`.  It may also be more readable and better practice to not use global variables (`Count`).  Your second code block could be simpler: `int digitsCount(int n){if(n <= 0) return 0; return digitsCount(n / 10) + 1;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider how the answer changes as you increase the number of digits:

- 1 digit - `false`
- 2 digits - `true`
- 3 digit - `false`
- 4 digits - `true`
- and so on

See the pattern? The answer to a problem with one digit is `false`, and the answer to a problem with `n+1` digits is the inverse of the answer for the problem with `n` digits.

Since you already know that reducing the number of digits by one is done by dividing by 10 in integers, you should be able to write a solution to the above algorithm with just a few lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

Recursion is to express the function in terms of itself, but for a smaller problem. Something like this:

- If the number is 9 or lower, it's false.
- If the number is 99 or lower, it's true.
- Otherwise, divide by 100 and check if the result has an even number of digits...

Answer (score 0):

Since we know that Number%2 will return 0 or 1, i'm going to assume that you shouldn't be using that to determinate if the number is even or odd.

You should set your base case (If 1 then return false)

Then check if the n-1 was even or odd and return the opposite.

Comment: How is this different from other answers?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume we're only dealing with positive numbers, something like this could be written:

```
public static boolean IsEven(int n)
{
    return n >= 10
        ? !IsEven(n / 10)
        : false;
}
```

Comment: Think I got it, 
here is my interpretation of this code (for numbers 236 and 9000),
please correct me, if Im wrong
https://s10.postimg.org/nmiyma6g9/example.jpg

Answer (score 0):

On the same line as mentioned by dasblinkenlight above

```
public static boolean isEven(int num){
        if(num>=10){
            return !isEven(num/10);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48177907/1300910) but with a bug, as it should be `num >= 10` instead of `num > 10`